# how can I indicate selection in a clickable FrameLayout?

Tags: android

I am trying to implement a clickable composite view.  The composite view is implemented using a FrameLayout which contains an inflated set of child views.  If the user taps anywhere in the FrameLayout, I would like to flash the view as if it was selected, and then perform some action.

Here is my current code:

```
private void fillFrameLayout(FrameLayout frame) {
    View disclosureItem = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.disclosure_item, frame);
    frame.setClickable(true);
    frame.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
    public void onClick(View v) {
            // Do something
        }
    });
}
```

Can someone please tell me how I can provide some visible feedback to the user when they tap the frame?  IE: select the frame in the same way that selection appears in a list or grid view.

Thanks.

Comment: I don't know if it's as simple as this, but does setting the view as focusable and focusableInTouchMode, plus possibly calling requestFocus() in the onClick(), work?  If that's not enough, would a [ColorStateList](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/res/ColorStateList.html) or a [StateListDrawable](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/drawable/StateListDrawable.html) do the job?

Answer (score 0):

You could define a background drawable with multiple drawables:

```
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

<item android:state_pressed="true"
      android:state_window_focused="true"
      android:drawable="@drawable/bg_selected" />

<item android:state_focused="true"
      android:state_window_focused="true"
      android:drawable="@drawable/bg_selected" />

<item android:state_selected="true"
      android:state_window_focused="true"
      android:drawable="@drawable/bg_selected />

<item android:drawable="@drawable/bg" />
```

In your layout, add this drawable as a background drawable:

```
<FrameLayout
    ...
    android:background="@color/bg_drawable" >
```

I hope this is what you meant?

Comment: This does the trick. I found a style called list_selector_background in the Android platform styles which I can apply to the frame. This is simply a color, but it is platform independent, so the selection background is appropriate for the device. See: [Android Styles](http://android.git.kernel.org/?p=platform/frameworks/base.git;a=blob;f=core/res/res/values/styles.xml;h=d7b654e49809cb97a35682754b1394af5c8bc88b;hb=HEAD).